How can I import ModHeader JSON profiles into Requestly?
I want to move my profiles from Modheader to Requestly Rules. I tried exporting the profiles in JSON format and Importing them in Requestly, but Requestly doesn't support import from Modheader JSON. It gives error - invalid format.
Is there a way to convert Modheader JSON to Requestly Compatible JSON?

ModHeader profiles can't be directly imported into Requestly. You can raise a feature request on Requestly Github - https://github.com/requestly/requestly/issues

Thanks @SachinJain. Created an Issue - https://github.com/requestly/requestly/issues/1642

This issue has been resolved. I will also add an answer.

There is a one-click migration possible from ModHeader to Requestly. Here's how you can do it.

Install Requestly Chrome Extension or Desktop App
Click on the Import Button
Import the ModHeader JSON Profile

Here is a direct link as well - https://app.requestly.io/import-from-modheader
